# constructing a choice set for the rational equivalence on the rational numbers

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I must explicitly construct a choice set on $\Bbb Q$.

The rational equivalence relation is as follows "Two numbers in a set are rationally equivalent provided their difference is rational".

I don't think this is possible, since any two rational numbers have rational difference, and so they cannot satisfy the requirement that any two points in the choice set have irrational difference.

Comment: You're right that any two rational numbers have rational difference, but I'm pretty sure by "two numbers" it means two _real_ numbers.

Comment: Indeed that is the definition of the rational equivalence, but I am asked to construct it on $\Bbb Q$, the rationals.

Comment: Perhaps you're overthinking it: unlike on $\Bbb R$, it's really easy to specify a choice set on $\Bbb Q$ :)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously every element of Q is rationally equivalent to every other element of Q.
Therefore any singleton element {q} ⊆ Q is a choice set.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that it's not possible to have two points in the choice set, since they would have to have irrational difference.  But that doesn't mean the choice set can't exist: it just means it must have fewer than two points!  Indeed, if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ is *any* element, then the set $S=\{x\}$ is a choice set, since for each element $y\in\mathbb{Q}$, there exists a unique element of $S$ which is equivalent to $y$ (namely, $x$).